# The program '[4800] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Trying to debug my code (site-project) like everyday
but got this error:

> The program '[4800] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Program Trace' has exited
>   with code 0 (0x0).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Every single time? When that kind of thing happens I just restart VS and it goes away...

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help. Will try again

Comment: Are you using custom controls?

Answer (score 1):

VS restart solved the issue. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this happen before when our code created an infinite recursion loop (i.e. stack overflow). I suspect that is could be your issue based on the exit code.

If you have a dialog that is displayed that gives you an opportunity to debug, try clicking on the debug button and looking at the stack trace. It should be fairly obvious if there is code in an infinite recursion loop.

Comment: I don't even reach to debug mode

Comment: @user1065869: Sorry, didn't mean debug mode. Sometimes when an unhandled exception is encountered, you have an opportunity to debug the program through a dialog that is displayed. If you are not seeing a dialog, then this suggestion won't help you.